# Spark code shuts down on using async functions to parallelise the rdds processing

Tags: apache-spark, asynchronous

Hello here is a simple spark code,and in my code,am trying to run processing on 2 rdds parallely using async functions.But when i run my code using async functionality,the spark code shuts down sayin "cannot call methods on stopped spark context". My system is dual core.

Here is my code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark_auth").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)             
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(32, 34, 2, 3, 4, 54, 3))
rdd1.foreachAsync{ x =>  println("Items in the list:"+x)}
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("1"))
rdd2.foreachAsync{ y =>  println("y is:"+y)}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "asyncTest"

version := "2.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.1"

  )
```

Error Log:

```
17/06/19 04:29:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
17/06/19 04:29:41 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (foreachAsync at test.scala:13) failed in Unknown s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:76)
test.test$.main(test.scala:10)
test.test.main(test.scala)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:76)
test.test$.main(test.scala:10)
test.test.main(test.scala)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:76)
test.test$.main(test.scala:10)
test.test.main(test.scala)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:76)
test.test$.main(test.scala:10)
test.test.main(test.scala)

        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:996)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:862)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1613)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

17/06/19 04:29:41 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@41103bce)
17/06/19 04:29:41 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(0,1497846581465,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
```

To check on how to run processes parallely in spark i reffered https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/10/21/demystifying-asynchronous-actions-in-spark/.
Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this error? Or is there a better approach on parallelising spark rdd processing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This error is usually an indication of a previous error which caused the `SparkContext` to stop. Is that the full log?

Comment: yes Yuval thats it.If i remove async functions and do any other spark functionaltiy,the code works fine,but on using async,this error is been thrown.